# Extend Dialog goes wrong in android

Tags: android

I extend a Dialog

java code

```
public class Dialog_query extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {   

}
```

Through the XML defines a interface
[image]

Now want to select date by clicking on 日期1
The code is as follow
Recorded as:code button

java button

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnDate);           
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
          public void onClick(View v) {   
            new DatePickerDialog(Dialog_query.this,   
                d2,   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)   
                ).show();   
          }   
        });
```

Now the question is,point out"The constructor DatePickerDialog(Dialog_query, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, int, int, int) is undefined"

Later found in here to add"Toast.makeText(LoginSuccess.this, "About agile software 1.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();"

also point out"The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not  applicable for the arguments (Dialog_query, String, int)"

But the "code button" is right in Activity.

Why in the extend cases will prompt such a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're Dialog_query inheritates from dialog. But the Dialog class does not inheritate from Activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

The constructor of DatePickerDialog needs a context or activity. Put the name of your activity instead of Dialog_query.this

```
new DatePickerDialog(ActivityName.this,   
                d2,   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),   
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)   
                ).show();
```